# If $x\cos \theta + y\sin \theta = z$, then what is the value of $(x\sin \theta - y\cos \theta)^2$?

Tags: trigonometry

Where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are variables. Answer in terms of these variables only, please.

Comment: Is there anything you personally can say about the problem? Tools that you've learned about and have considered (or even better, tried!) using, or attempts you've made that haven't worked out?

Comment: I had considered squarring both the sides but couldn't proceed further.

Answer (score 3):

$$x \cos \theta + y \sin \theta =z \implies x^2 \cos^2 \theta + y^2 \sin^2 \theta + 2 x y \sin \theta \cos \theta =z^2 \tag1$$

Let $$(x \sin \theta - y \cos \theta)^2 = x^2 \sin^2 \theta + y^2 \cos^2 \theta -2 x y \sin \theta \cos \theta = w \tag2$$

Adding $(1) $ and $(2)$

$$x^2+y^2=w+z^2 \implies (x \sin \theta - y \cos \theta)^2=x^2+y^2-z^2$$